# jQuery CSS Opacity

Tags: jquery, css, block, opacity

What's wrong? I want to change the opacity if `#nav .drop` is `display:block;`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if (jQuery('#nav .drop').css('display') === 'block') {
        jQuery('#main').css('opacity') = '0.6';
    }
});
```

Comment: Try this jQuery('#main').css({'opacity':0.6}) ;

Comment: Is this for a drop down menu? Presumably if the drop is not `display: block` it is hidden, so why not just set it permanently to 60% opacity? Or am I missing something? It would be nice to see a working example of this.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```
jQuery('#main').css('opacity') = '0.6';
```

should be

```
jQuery('#main').css('opacity', '0.6');
```

Update:

http://jsfiddle.net/GegMk/ if you type in the text box. Click away, the opacity changes.

Comment: yep, found that just in time, but it still dont work. Any other idea?

Comment: Opacity value should not be a string, so:

'jQuery('#main').css('opacity', 0.6);'

Answer (score 27):

Try with this :

```
jQuery('#main').css({ opacity: 0.6 });
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#main').css('opacity', '0.6');
```

or

```
jQuery('#main').css({'filter':'alpha(opacity=60)', 'zoom':'1', 'opacity':'0.6'});
```

if you want to support **IE7**, **IE8** and so on.

Answer (score 0):

try using .animate instead of .css or even just on the opacity one and leave .css on the display?? may b

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if (jQuery('#nav .drop').animate('display') === 'block') {
    jQuery('#main').animate('opacity') = '0.6';
```